# Question regarding aposematism

Tags: entomology

Are all aposematic insects chemically defended? Can there be insects that mimic chemically defended insects that are also aposematic?

Any ideas?

Comment: I *think* you're talking about Batesian mimickry. For example, hoverfly species without stings mimic wasp species (with bright black and yellow striped patterns) which do have them. And there are several examples in the butterfly world. Males of the species Danaus chrysippus are inedible due to their consumption of plants containing toxic chemicals. They are also aposematic. Females of that species, as well as butterflies of other species, mimic D. chrysippus males. Can you let me know if this is the sort of thing you're asking about, so I can turn this into an answer if so?

Comment: @Astrid_Redfern The question asks "are all aposematic insects chemically defended"? The way I see this is: "Is part of the definition of aposematism, that the insect that has this attribute is chemically defended?" I want to be sure about the answer, but the main thing that confuses me is this: "Can an edible insect that mimics an inedible model with bright colors or some aposematic-like attribute be defined to be aposematic?"

Comment: I think the answer to the question would be "no, an aposematic insect must be chemically defended, if it is not, and it is a mimic, then it exhibits batesian mimicry, not aposematism.

Comment: @Astrid_Redfern what do you think?